# Approximate ST_GeneratePoints in SpatiaLite

Tags: spatialite, random

Is there an efficient way to approximate [ST_GeneratePoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html) in SpatiaLite?

Here's one approach I can think of: get the bounding box of a geometry, then generate random points within the box using the standard `random()` function, and finally find the random points that intersect with the original geometry.

That would probably need to be implemented recursively to ensure that you actually got the desired number of points.

Comment: here a probable solution, Italian language:
https://pigrecoinfinito.com/2019/05/17/spatialite-generare-punti-casuali-in-un-bounding-box-di-un-poligono/